# Perl regex for currency matching

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to error check the format of a string $price

The string will start with a Currency symbol. (As there are so many of them, I'm going to skip that, so show that below as ?)

So the CORRECT formats are "?12.34" or "? 2.34" or "?2.34" Incorrect would be "1234" / "234"

So first of all I check for the negative match for a decimal, using a global search (Now the fun regex) I'm trying to check the NEGATIVE (ie does NOT conform to) one or two digits 0-9, a decimal followed by two digits 0-9. I came up with the following (untested) theory pattern. As it's my first complex regex, have I got it right?

```
if ($price eq ''){
say'';
say 'You did not enter any price. Try again';
say'';
}
elsif ($price !~ /\./g ){
say'';
say 'Please include a decimal point';
say'';
}
elsif ($price !~ /[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}$/){
say'';
say 'Please check the format of price (XX.XX)';
say'';
```

Comment: Your last regex handles the two prior if's, so you can are it into just one if.  This won't work for Japanese yen because they don't use decimal.

Comment: You could store the currency symbols in a string and put that first. Then it it should be prefixed with `^` to indicate the beginning of the string.

Comment: "there are so many of them" – in that case, be aware that ~half the world places the currency symbol _after_ the amount; it is not always one character; and not all currencies use decimals at all.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Re the last regex traps the same as the first two, agreed, but the prompt to user is not so 'global' (If they enter an empty string,and see the format is incorrect ...)
... I did think of putting the Currency in a string, but that means putting all the unicodes in script etc as keyboard only does $ and £

Comment: Thanks for the insight that some currencies use them at the end, and some no decimal. That could make life interesting ! So I think I'll stick with US$, CAD$ and £ and Euro for now !

Comment: `\p{Sc}` is the unicode property for all currency symbol. `^(?:\p{Sc})?\h*\d\d?\.\d\d\h*(?:\p{Sc})?$` will match values preceded or followed by currency symbol. For currencies abbreviations it is much more complex I suggest you remove the non digit or dot from the string, then test with your actual regex.

Comment: So \p{Sc} will match on £, $, (Euro,Yen etc. Not on my keyboard)? I can 'sort of' see \d\d\.\d\d  as  matching one or two digits before or after a decimal, but in the dark- research needed -re \h* and question mark/colon (?:\p{Sc}

Comment: From what I've researched,the above is "(?:\p{Sc}) an 'if-then' shorthand to say there may or may not be any currency symbol here", "(\h*) any white space", "(\d) a numeric digit", "(\d?) a numeric digit of 0 or more", "(\.) a dot", "(\d\d") two digits, "(\h*) any whitespaces ( "(?:\p{Sc})" another if-then to say there may be a Currency Symbol here .... in case anyone else is trying to follow it . That should work great, thanks. (Only slight proviso; some  have said some currencies don't feature a  decimal. I'll have to supply a second script for those users